# Form (with Jquery) submitting empty values

Tags: jquery, html, forms, jsp, post

My form is submitting the 3 fields in my form, but when i look in firebug it is posting nothing. Im wondering if its my jquery causing the problem but im not sure.

So the populateData function, checks which countryCode, and then depending on that populates the CountryCode1 field.

Any idea why my form would be submitting empty values?

```
<script>
    function submitform()
{
    document.mobileLinkForm.submit();
}

    function populateData(value,phone){
        if(value=='GB'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("44");}
        if(value=='IE'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("353");}
        if(value=='DE'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("49");}
        if(value=='NZ'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("64");}
        if(value=='AF'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("93");}
        if(value=='AL'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("355");}
        if(value=='DZ'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("213");}
        if(value=='AS'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("1684");}
        if(value=='AD'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("376");}
        if(value=='AO'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("244");}
        if(value=='AI'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("1264");}
        if(value=='AQ'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("672");}
        if(value=='AG'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("1268");}
        if(value=='AR'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("54");}
        if(value=='AM'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("374");}
        if(value=='AW'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("297");}
        if(value=='AT'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("43");}
        if(value=='AZ'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("994");}
        if(value=='BS'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("1242");}
        if(value=='BH'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("973");}
        if(value=='BD'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("880");}
        if(value=='BB'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("1246");}
        if(value=='BY'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("375");}
        if(value=='BZ'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("501");}
        if(value=='BJ'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("229");}
        if(value=='BM'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("1441");}
        if(value=='BT'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("975");}
        if(value=='BO'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("591");}
        if(value=='BA'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("387");}
        if(value=='BW'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("267");}
        if(value=='IO'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("246");}
        if(value=='BR'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("55");}
        if(value=='BN'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("673");}
        if(value=='BG'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("359");}
        if(value=='BF'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("226");}
        if(value=='BI'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("257");}
        if(value=='CF'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("236");}
        if(value=='KH'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("855");}
        if(value=='CM'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("237");}
        if(value=='CV'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("238");}
        if(value=='KY'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("1345");}
        if(value=='TD'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("235");}
        if(value=='CL'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("56");}
        if(value=='CX'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("61");}
        if(value=='CC'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("61");}
        if(value=='CO'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("57");}
        if(value=='KM'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("269");}
        if(value=='CG'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("242");}
        if(value=='CD'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("243");}
        if(value=='CR'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("506");}
        if(value=='CI'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("225");}
        if(value=='HR'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("385");}
        if(value=='CY'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("357");}
        if(value=='CZ'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("420");}
        if(value=='DJ'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("253");}
        if(value=='DM'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("1767");}
        if(value=='DO'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("1809");}
        if(value=='EC'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("593");}
        if(value=='EG'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("20");}
        if(value=='SV'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("503");}
        if(value=='GQ'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("240");}
        if(value=='ER'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("291");}
        if(value=='ET'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("251");}
        if(value=='FK'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("500");}
        if(value=='FO'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("298");}
        if(value=='FJ'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("679");}
        if(value=='FI'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("358");}
        if(value=='GA'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("241");}
        if(value=='GM'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("220");}
        if(value=='GE'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("995");}
        if(value=='GH'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("233");}
        if(value=='GI'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("350");}
        if(value=='GR'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("30");}
        if(value=='GL'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("299");}
        if(value=='GD'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("1473");}
        if(value=='GU'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("1671");}
        if(value=='GT'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("502");}
        if(value=='GG'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("44");}
        if(value=='GN'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("224");}
        if(value=='GW'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("245");}
        if(value=='GY'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("592");}
        if(value=='HT'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("509");}
        if(value=='HN'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("504");}
        if(value=='HU'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("36");}
        if(value=='IS'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("354");}
        if(value=='ID'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("62");}
        if(value=='IM'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("44");}
        if(value=='IT'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("39");}
        if(value=='JM'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("1876");}
        if(value=='JP'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("81");}
        if(value=='JE'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("44");}
        if(value=='JO'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("962");}
        if(value=='KZ'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("7");}
        if(value=='KE'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("254");}
        if(value=='KI'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("686");}
        if(value=='KW'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("965");}
        if(value=='KG'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("996");}
        if(value=='LV'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("371");}
        if(value=='LB'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("961");}
        if(value=='LS'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("266");}
        if(value=='LR'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("231");}
        if(value=='LI'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("423");}
        if(value=='LT'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("370");}
        if(value=='LU'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("352");}
        if(value=='MO'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("853");}
        if(value=='MK'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("389");}
        if(value=='MG'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("261");}
        if(value=='MW'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("265");}
        if(value=='MY'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("60");}
        if(value=='MV'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("960");}
        if(value=='ML'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("223");}
        if(value=='MT'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("356");}
        if(value=='MH'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("692");}
        if(value=='MR'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("222");}
        if(value=='MU'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("230");}
        if(value=='MX'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("52");}
        if(value=='FM'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("691");}
        if(value=='MD'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("373");}
        if(value=='MN'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("976");}
        if(value=='ME'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("382");}
        if(value=='MS'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("1664");}
        if(value=='MA'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("212");}
        if(value=='MZ'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("258");}
        if(value=='NA'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("264");}
        if(value=='NP'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("977");}
        if(value=='AN'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("599");}
        if(value=='NC'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("687");}
        if(value=='NI'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("505");}
        if(value=='NE'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("227");}
        if(value=='NU'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("683");}
        if(value=='NF'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("672");}
        if(value=='MP'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("1670");}
        if(value=='OM'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("968");}
        if(value=='PK'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("92");}
        if(value=='PW'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("680");}
        if(value=='PS'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("970");}
        if(value=='PA'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("507");}
        if(value=='PG'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("675");}
        if(value=='PY'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("595");}
        if(value=='PE'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("51");}
        if(value=='PH'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("63");}
        if(value=='PN'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("870");}
        if(value=='PL'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("48");}
        if(value=='PT'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("351");}
        if(value=='PR'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("1");}
        if(value=='QA'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("974");}
        if(value=='RO'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("40");}
        if(value=='RW'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("250");}
        if(value=='SH'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("290");}
        if(value=='WS'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("685");}
        if(value=='SM'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("378");}
        if(value=='ST'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("239");}
        if(value=='SA'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("966");}
        if(value=='SN'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("221");}
        if(value=='RS'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("381");}
        if(value=='SC'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("248");}
        if(value=='SL'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("232");}
        if(value=='SG'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("65");}
        if(value=='SK'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("421");}
        if(value=='SI'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("386");}
        if(value=='SB'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("677");}
        if(value=='LK'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("94");}
        if(value=='KN'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("1869");}
        if(value=='LC'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("758");}
        if(value=='VC'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("784");}
        if(value=='GS'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("500");}
        if(value=='SR'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("597");}
        if(value=='SJ'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("47");}
        if(value=='SZ'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("268");}
        if(value=='SE'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("46");}
        if(value=='CH'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("41");}
        if(value=='SY'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("963");}
        if(value=='TJ'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("992");}
        if(value=='TZ'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("255");}
        if(value=='TL'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("670");}
        if(value=='TG'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("228");}
        if(value=='TK'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("690");}
        if(value=='TO'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("676");}
        if(value=='TT'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("1868");}
        if(value=='TN'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("216");}
        if(value=='TM'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("993");}
        if(value=='TC'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("1649");}
        if(value=='TV'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("688");}
        if(value=='UG'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("256");}
        if(value=='UA'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("380");}
        if(value=='AE'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("971");}
        if(value=='UY'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("598");}
        if(value=='VU'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("678");}
        if(value=='VA'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("39");}
        if(value=='VE'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("58");}
        if(value=='VN'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("84");}
        if(value=='VG'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("284");}
        if(value=='VI'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("340");}
        if(value=='WF'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("681");}
        if(value=='EH'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("212");}
        if(value=='YE'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("967");}
        if(value=='ZM'){$('#countryCode'+phone).val("260");}
    }
</script>

<ssl:form action="mobileLink" name="mobileLinkForm">
                <select property="map(countryCode)" onchange="populateData(this.value,1)">
                    <option value="">Please select your country:</option>
                    <option value="GB">UNITED KINGDOM</option>
                    <option value="IE">IRELAND</option>
                    <option value="DE">GERMANY</option>
                    <option value="NZ">NEW ZEALAND</option>
                    <option value="AF">AFGHANISTAN</option>
                    <option value="AL">ALBANIA</option>
                    <option value="DZ">ALGERIA</option>
                    <option value="AS">AMERICAN SAMOA</option>
                    <option value="AD">ANDORRA</option>
                    <option value="AO">ANGOLA</option>
                    <option value="AI">ANGUILLA</option>
                    <option value="AQ">ANTARCTICA</option>
                    <option value="AG">ANTIGUA AND BARBUDA</option>
                    <option value="AR">ARGENTINA</option>
                    <option value="AM">ARMENIA</option>
                    <option value="AW">ARUBA</option>
                    <option value="AT">AUSTRIA</option>
                    <option value="AZ">AZERBAIDJAN</option>
                    <option value="BS">BAHAMAS</option>
                    <option value="BH">BAHRAIN</option>
                    <option value="BD">BANGLADESH</option>
                    <option value="BB">BARBADOS</option>
                    <option value="BY">BELARUS</option>
                    <option value="BZ">BELIZE</option>
                    <option value="BJ">BENIN</option>
                    <option value="BM">BERMUDA</option>
                    <option value="BT">BHUTAN</option>
                    <option value="BO">BOLIVIA</option>
                    <option value="BA">BOSNIA-HERZEGOVINA</option>
                    <option value="BW">BOTSWANA</option>
                    <option value="IO">BR INDIAN O TERRITORY</option>
                    <option value="BR">BRAZIL</option>
                    <option value="BN">BRUNEI DARUSSALAM</option>
                    <option value="BG">BULGARIA</option>
                    <option value="BF">BURKINA FASO</option>
                    <option value="BI">BURUNDI</option>
                    <option value="CF">C AFRICAN REPUBLIC</option>
                    <option value="KH">CAMBODIA</option>
                    <option value="CM">CAMEROON</option>
                    <option value="CV">CAPE VERDE</option>
                    <option value="KY">CAYMAN ISLANDS</option>
                    <option value="TD">CHAD</option>
                    <option value="CL">CHILE</option>
                    <option value="CX">CHRISTMAS ISLAND</option>
                    <option value="CC">COCOS ISLANDS</option>
                    <option value="CO">COLOMBIA</option>
                    <option value="KM">COMOROS</option>
                    <option value="CG">CONGO</option>
                    <option value="CD">CONGO, DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF</option>
                    <option value="CR">COSTA RICA</option>
                    <option value="CI">COTE D'IVOIRE</option>
                    <option value="HR">CROATIA</option>
                    <option value="CY">CYPRUS</option>
                    <option value="CZ">CZECH REPUBLIC</option>
                    <option value="DJ">DJIBOUTI</option>
                    <option value="DM">DOMINICA</option>
                    <option value="DO">DOMINICAN REPUBLIC</option>
                    <option value="EC">ECUADOR</option>
                    <option value="EG">EGYPT</option>
                    <option value="SV">EL SALVADOR</option>
                    <option value="GQ">EQUATORIAL GUINEA</option>
                    <option value="ER">ERITREA</option>
                    <option value="ET">ETHIOPIA</option>
                    <option value="FK">FALKLAND ISLANDS</option>
                    <option value="FO">FAROE ISLANDS</option>
                    <option value="FJ">FIJI</option>
                    <option value="FI">FINLAND</option>
                    <option value="GA">GABON</option>
                    <option value="GM">GAMBIA</option>
                    <option value="GE">GEORGIA</option>
                    <option value="GH">GHANA</option>
                    <option value="GI">GIBRALTAR</option>
                    <option value="GR">GREECE</option>
                    <option value="GL">GREENLAND</option>
                    <option value="GD">GRENADA</option>
                    <option value="GU">GUAM</option>
                    <option value="GT">GUATEMALA</option>
                    <option value="GG">GUERNSEY</option>
                    <option value="GN">GUINEA</option>
                    <option value="GW">GUINEA BISSAU</option>
                    <option value="GY">GUYANA</option>
                    <option value="HM">H AND MCD ISLANDS</option>
                    <option value="HT">HAITI</option>
                    <option value="HN">HONDURAS</option>
                    <option value="HU">HUNGARY</option>
                    <option value="IS">ICELAND</option>
                    <option value="ID">INDONESIA</option>
                    <option value="IM">ISLE OF MAN</option>
                    <option value="IT">ITALY</option>
                    <option value="JM">JAMAICA</option>
                    <option value="JP">JAPAN</option>
                    <option value="JE">JERSEY</option>
                    <option value="JO">JORDAN</option>
                    <option value="KZ">KAZAKHSTAN</option>
                    <option value="KE">KENYA</option>
                    <option value="KI">KIRIBATI</option>
                    <option value="KW">KUWAIT</option>
                    <option value="KG">KYRGYESTAN</option>
                    <option value="LV">LATVIA</option>
                    <option value="LB">LEBANON</option>
                    <option value="LS">LESOTHO</option>
                    <option value="LR">LIBERIA</option>
                    <option value="LI">LIECHTENSTEIN</option>
                    <option value="LT">LITHUANIA</option>
                    <option value="LU">LUXEMBOURG</option>
                    <option value="MO">MACAO</option>
                    <option value="MK">MACEDONIA, FMR YUGOSLAV RPBLC</option>
                    <option value="MG">MADAGASCAR</option>
                    <option value="MW">MALAWI</option>
                    <option value="MY">MALAYSIA</option>
                    <option value="MV">MALDIVES</option>
                    <option value="ML">MALI</option>
                    <option value="MT">MALTA</option>
                    <option value="MH">MARSHALL ISLANDS</option>
                    <option value="MR">MAURITANIA</option>
                    <option value="MU">MAURITIUS</option>
                    <option value="MX">MEXICO</option>
                    <option value="FM">MICRONESIA</option>
                    <option value="MD">MOLDOVA</option>
                    <option value="MN">MONGOLIA</option>
                    <option value="ME">MONTENEGRO</option>
                    <option value="MS">MONTSERRAT</option>
                    <option value="MA">MOROCCO</option>
                    <option value="MZ">MOZAMBIQUE</option>
                    <option value="NA">NAMIBIA</option>
                    <option value="NP">NEPAL</option>
                    <option value="AN">NETHERLAND ANTILLES</option>
                    <option value="NC">NEW CALEDONIA</option>
                    <option value="NI">NICARAGU</option>
                    <option value="NE">NIGER</option>
                    <option value="NU">NIUE</option>
                    <option value="NF">NORFOLK ISLAND</option>
                    <option value="MP">NORTHERN MARIANA ISLANDS</option>
                    <option value="OM">OMAN</option>
                    <option value="PK">PAKISTAN</option>
                    <option value="PW">PALAU</option>
                    <option value="PS">PALESTINIAN TERRITORIES</option>
                    <option value="PA">PANAMA</option>
                    <option value="PG">PAPUA NEW</option>
                    <option value="PY">PARAGUAY</option>
                    <option value="PE">PERU</option>
                    <option value="PH">PHILIPPINES</option>
                    <option value="PN">PITCAIRN</option>
                    <option value="PL">POLAND</option>
                    <option value="PT">PORTUGAL</option>
                    <option value="PR">PUERTO RICO</option>
                    <option value="QA">QATAR</option>
                    <option value="RO">ROMANIA</option>
                    <option value="RW">RWANDA</option>
                    <option value="SH">SAINT HELENA</option>
                    <option value="WS">SAMOA</option>
                    <option value="SM">SAN MARINO</option>
                    <option value="ST">SAO TOME AND PRINCIPE</option>
                    <option value="SA">SAUDI ARABIA</option>
                    <option value="SN">SENEGAL</option>
                    <option value="RS">SERBIA</option>
                    <option value="SC">SEYCHELLES</option>
                    <option value="SL">SIERRA LEONE</option>
                    <option value="SG">SINGAPORE</option>
                    <option value="SK">SLOVAKIA</option>
                    <option value="SI">SLOVENIA</option>
                    <option value="SB">SOLOMON ISLANDS</option>
                    <option value="LK">SRI LANKA</option>
                    <option value="KN">ST KITTS NEVIS ANGUILLA</option>
                    <option value="LC">ST LUCIA</option>
                    <option value="VC">ST VINC AND GRENADINES</option>
                    <option value="GS">STH GEORGIA &amp; STH SANDWCH ISL</option>
                    <option value="SR">SURI</option>
                    <option value="SJ">SVALBARD AND JAN MAYEN</option>
                    <option value="SZ">SWAZILAND</option>
                    <option value="SE">SWEDEN</option>
                    <option value="CH">SWITZERLAND</option>
                    <option value="SY">SYRIA</option>
                    <option value="TJ">TAJIKISTAN</option>
                    <option value="TZ">TANZANIA</option>
                    <option value="TP">TIMOR-LESTE</option>
                    <option value="TG">TOGO</option>
                    <option value="TK">TOKELAU</option>
                    <option value="TO">TONGA</option>
                    <option value="TT">TRINIDAD AND TOBAGO</option>
                    <option value="TN">TUNISIA</option>
                    <option value="TM">TURKMENISTAN</option>
                    <option value="TC">TURKS AND CAICOS IS </option>
                    <option value="TV">TUVALU</option>
                    <option value="UG">UGANDA</option>
                    <option value="UA">UKRAINE</option>
                    <option value="AE">UNITED ARAB EMIRATES</option>
                    <option value="UY">URUGUAY</option>
                    <option value="VU">VANUATU</option>
                    <option value="VA">VATICAN CITY STATE</option>
                    <option value="VE">VENEZUELA</option>
                    <option value="VN">VIETNAM</option>
                    <option value="VG">VIRGIN ISLANDS (BRITISH)</option>
                    <option value="VI">VIRGIN ISLANDS (US)</option>
                    <option value="WF">WALLIS AND FUTUNA IS </option>
                    <option value="EH">WESTERN SAHARA</option>
                    <option value="YE">YEMEN</option>
                    <option value="ZM">ZAMBIA</option>
                    </select>
                <input property="map(mobileCode)" name="countryCode" id="countryCode1" class="country-code" value="" readonly="true" />
                <input property="map(mobileNumber)" class="telephone" value="mobileNumber" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='mobileNumber';" onfocus="if(this.value=='mobileNumber')this.value='';" />
                <a href="javascript:submitform()"></a>

            </ssl:form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed the 'name' attribute from your form fields. For example,

```
<input property="map(mobileCode)" id="countryCode1"
     class="country-code" value="" readonly="true" />
```

should be

```
<input property="map(mobileCode)" id="countryCode1"
     name="countryCode" class="country-code" value="" readonly="true" />
```

Your browser will use these name fields when it submits the data back to the server.

Comment: Thanks @Adrian Wragg, my 44 submitted for mobileCode. However countryCode & mobileNumber didnt submit.

Comment: Can you post the updated HTML, just so I (or someone else) can check that the 'name' attributes are correct on all three fields?

Comment: Have updated the html. (added name to the map(mobileCode input).

Comment: You need to put the `name` attribute on the other two as well; the sample I posted was simply an indication of the change needed to all three fields.

Comment: Ahh i see now, its because I didnt write it in jsp because of the onchange event, so i wrote it in html and forgot to change property to name. Thanks @Adrian-Wragg

Answer (score 0):

Instead `<ssl:form>` use `<form>` tag.

And you missed `forms` in this line:

```
document.mobileLinkForm.submit();
```

Should be:

```
document.forms.mobileLinkForm.submit();
```

And I would encourage you to minimize you code by writing something like this:

```
<select property="map(countryCode)" onchange="populateData(this,1)">
    <option value="PL" data-prefix="48">POLAND</option>
</select>
```

and JavaScript:

```
function populateData (select, phone) {
    var value = $(select).val();
    var prefix = $(select).find('option[value="'+ value +'"]').data('prefix');
    $('#countryCode' + phone).val(prefix);
}
```

You could go even further but it wasn't the question.